# Adding VBA listobject without changing format

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I got the following problem. I have a formated table in an excel-sheet. Via an Add-In I want to add that table to an MicrosoftWord template and save it as pdf.
For this I use the following Code:

```
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.UsedRange, , xlYes)
Set DocRef = doc.Bookmarks("Table1").Range
ws.ListObjects(1).Range.Copy
DocRef.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
```

My problem with this is, that the ListObject.Add function changes the format of the cells. Also i dont necessary want the Code to head Columnheaders. Is there a way to use ListObject.Add without any changes in format oder do you know a better way to copy the cells to Word and print them as pdf?

Thank you :)

Comment: If you already have a formatted table, why are you trying to add another one?

Comment: its not a formatted table. I just made some manual formattig. I use the ListObject, because its handy to use to export the table to Word.

Comment: Why? You already know the range you want, since you have to use it to create the table, so just copy that range using `ws.usedrange.copy`

Comment: ohhh....
Thank you :) for some reason i was fixed on the thought that .pasteExcelTable requiered a formatted table...
Well im stupid. Thanks :)